# Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, is.na(result) & data_col, value = c(NA_real_, : 'value' is the wrong length

Tags: r, cast

Tengo un data_frame (denominado mes_e) con 4 columnas y sus respectivos nombre: fecha, dia, mes, esp.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando intento calcular los cuantiles del 1 al 9 de la siguiente forma:

```
e_result <- cast(mes_e, mes~., quantile, seq(0.1,0.9,0.1), value='esp', na.rm=TRUE)
```

Me aparece el siguiente error:

> Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, is.na(result) & data_col, value = c(NA_real_,  :
> 'value' is the wrong length

Sin embargo, si voy calculando los nueve percentiles uno a uno de la siguiente manera:

```
e_result <- cast(mes_e, mes~., quantile, 0.1, value='esp', na.rm=TRUE)
```

Me hace el cálculo correctamente.

¿A qué se puede deber?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Bienvenido user218584 a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: No logro reproducir tu problema, el código con unos datos arbitrarios creado para tal fin, funciona bien. ¿Podrías crear un [mcve] que reproduzca el problema?